# Elementor single post - images wider than text

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I'm using Elementor Pro. My blog design needs images to be wider than text in Single Post Template (example: text will be max 840px wide, while images can be 1140px wide). Unfortunately, post editor while inserting image puts it inside of `<p>` tag so I can't just do it easy way `p{ max-width: 840px } img{ max-width: 1140px }`. I can't change post editor as my client requires it to stay the way it is. I've also tried to solve it by making container of post content 840px wide, and then adding CSS `img{ max-width: 1140px; width: 1140px; margin-left: -100px }`, but this makes another problem: not all images have that high quality so they end up stretched. I could also not add `width: 1140px` for `img`, but then image is not centered.

What's the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the image, and edit.

Style > Width and resize it